# Counting how many times a value occurs in a json file

Tags: python, json

how do i read count how many times each "type" and "key" occurs in a  json file with data like below

```
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:46392970","dataset":"deCarta","production":true,"type":"REVERSEGEOCODE","path":"/v1/04track12netics2015/reverseGeocode/-28.45818,24.39608.xml?returnSpeedLimit=true","key":"04track12netics2015","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":5,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T23:59:52.975Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:46392915","dataset":"deCarta","production":true,"type":"REVERSEGEOCODE","path":"/v1/04track12netics2015/reverseGeocode/-25.96607,28.14167.xml?returnSpeedLimit=true","key":"04track12netics2015","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":96,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T23:59:53.011Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:46393163","dataset":"deCarta","production":true,"type":"REVERSEGEOCODE","path":"/v1/04track12netics2015/reverseGeocode/-28.45818,24.39608.xml?returnSpeedLimit=true","key":"04track12netics2015","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":7,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T23:59:53.170Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:81986956","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo/tile/1185/1176/11.png?settings=russian-river&res=mdpi","key":"fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":438,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T06:06:27.394Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:81987014","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo/tile/1185/1177/11.png?settings=russian-river&res=mdpi","key":"fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":390,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T06:06:27.404Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:81986884","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo/tile/1183/1175/11.png?settings=russian-river&res=mdpi","key":"fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":533,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T06:06:27.417Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:41422853","dataset":"TomTom","production":true,"type":"SEARCH","path":"/v1/fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo/search/0A%20Schoonder%20Stree,.json?countrySet=ZA","key":"fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":824,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T22:37:03.677Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:88284444","dataset":"deCarta","production":true,"type":"REVERSEGEOCODE","path":"/v1/fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo/reverseGeocode/-33.92456,18.54727.json","key":"fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":170,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T07:51:24.615Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:10992447","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN/tile/18063/19670/15.png?transparent=true&settings=russian-river&res=hdpi","key":"CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":407,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-21T20:23:12.854Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:10992826","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN/tile/18060/19670/15.png?transparent=true&settings=russian-river&res=hdpi","key":"CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":219,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-21T20:23:13.046Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:46392970","dataset":"deCarta","production":true,"type":"REVERSEGEOCODE","path":"/v1/04track12netics2015/reverseGeocode/-28.45818,24.39608.xml?returnSpeedLimit=true","key":"04track12netics2015","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":5,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T23:59:52.975Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:46392915","dataset":"deCarta","production":true,"type":"REVERSEGEOCODE","path":"/v1/04track12netics2015/reverseGeocode/-25.96607,28.14167.xml?returnSpeedLimit=true","key":"04track12netics2015","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":1,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":96,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T23:59:53.011Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:81986949","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo/tile/1182/1175/11.png?settings=russian-river&res=mdpi","key":"fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":472,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-12T06:06:27.421Z"}
{"method":"GET","UDID":"26:90:A4:10992826","dataset":"tomtom-world","production":true,"type":"TILE","path":"/v1/CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN/tile/18060/19670/15.png?transparent=true&settings=russian-river&res=hdpi","key":"CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN","cost":1,"vendorCost":{"dataProvider":0.03125,"trafficProvider":0},"roundTripTime":219,"nonCompQuery":0,"level":"request","message":"Processing Request","timestamp":"2016-08-21T20:23:13.046Z"}
```

Comment: Please explain your difficulties by actually showing the code you wrote and explicitly indicate where in your code you are having difficulty. From what you attempted, where are your errors/issues? If you are getting some kind of output from your current code, show what it currently looks like, and then indicate what it should look like.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file.

Comment: Please note, that this is not a free
   code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers
   (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics
   on [How to ask a good
   question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards,
   please update your question with the code you have written thus far
   in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('logs.txt') as infile:
    data = (json.loads(line) for line in infile)
    counter = Counter((row['type'], row['key']) for row in data)

pprint(dict(counter))
```

Output:

```
{(u'REVERSEGEOCODE', u'04track12netics2015'): 5,
 (u'REVERSEGEOCODE', u'fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo'): 1,
 (u'SEARCH', u'fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo'): 1,
 (u'TILE', u'CxIQlYBhwykcIxtYwrrbltCDiJ4xUxfN'): 3,
 (u'TILE', u'fpOgtLY1ZF22m3va4FLkU52tsLmpaNyo'): 4}
```

Comment: thanks i wanted the counts for each combination,i apologize if the question wasn't specific am still a new user

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach, the keys and types hold the number of times each key and type occurs. good luck.

```
from collections import defaultdict
keys,types = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)
for jline in yourjsonfile.readlines():
    line=json.loads(jline)
    keys[line['key']] += 1
    types[line['type']] += 1
```

Comment: You're duplicating code and paying the price for it: you forgot a `+1` at the end. But also it's completely wrong because you reassigned `keys` from a dictionary to a number. And you forgot to parse the JSON. You should really  test this kind of code before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, edited it

Comment: You can just write `keys[line['key']] += 1`.